# Copying subtotal to a new worksheet in Excel using VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I am filtering a large data set on the first sheet in my workbook and then I am creating a separate worksheet in the workbook for each unique name in the first column of the main data set.

After I filter the main data set for a given name, I am attempting to subtotal a particular filtered column (let's say column C), for example:

```
Sub CreateSheets()

    Dim wsCurrent As Worksheet
    Dim wsNew As Worksheet
    Dim iLeft As Integer
    Dim length As Long

    Set wsCurrent = ActiveSheet
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    'Copy list of all players and remove duplicates
    Range("A2", Range("A2").End(xlDown)).Copy Range("AY1")
    Range("AY1").CurrentRegion.RemoveDuplicates Columns:=1, Header:=xlYes

    'Iterator
    iLeft = Range("AY1").CurrentRegion.Rows.Count - 1

    'For each player
    Do While iLeft > 13
        Set wsNew = Worksheets.Add
        With wsCurrent.Range("A2").CurrentRegion
            'Player name from copied list
            .AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=wsCurrent.Range("AY1").Offset(iLeft).Value

            'Hits
            .AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria1:="1"
            length = .Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
            wsNew.Range("A1") = "=SUBTOTAL(9," & wsCurrent.Name & "!C2:C" & length & ")"

            'Turn off filters
            '.AutoFilter
        End With
        'Name player sheet and move onto next
        wsNew.Name = wsCurrent.Range("AY1").Offset(iLeft).Value
        iLeft = iLeft - 1
    Loop

    'Clear player names in copied region
    wsCurrent.Range("AY1").CurrentRegion.Clear
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

The main issue here is that the subtotal function call no longer find the referenced cell on the main sheet. Any help is much appreciated.

EDIT:

The following now provides the correct subtotal.

```
length = .Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
wsNew.Range("A1") = "=SUBTOTAL(9," & wsCurrent.Name & "!C2:C" & length & ")"
wsNew.Range("A1").Value = wsNew.Range("A1").Value
```

The last line ensures that when the filter is removed, the original sum of the visible cells remains (instead of then taking the sum of the visible cells with the filter now removed).

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried including the original sheet name as a reference in the Subtotal formula?

```
wsNew.Range("A1") = "=SUBTOTAL(9," & wsCurrent.Name & "!C2:C" & length & ")"
```

I replaced `9,C2:C` with `9, " & wsCurrent.Name & "!C2:C` which should reference it properly.

Comment: So when I run this, it prompts me to update values and open a file explorer from Excel? Any idea what this is for?

Comment: Did you copy my code exactly as is?  When I first wrote it I did not include the double quote and ampersands, so it looked like `SUBTOTAL(9,wsCurrent.Name!C2:C" & length & ")"` and when I tried to run that, it brought up the browse prompt.  Make sure you copy it exactly as I posted it originally and try again.  If it still fails, can you post what you are running?

Comment: So the update values error was occurring because my sheet name for the database included a space, so I resolved that issue. The only other thing is that the range reference on the new sheet (when I click in the cell) is as follows: =SUBTOTAL(9,Sheet1!C1:C2)    The range is incorrect.

Comment: Can you post the part of your updated code, a few lines above and a few lines below my changes? Hoping I can see another small issue because that should work. It didn't give me a reference error when I ran it through a test file.

Comment: My only idea is the dataset you are using. When you have the data filtered does your range extend past C1? If no data is populated and it is trying to reference C2:C1 it may be erroring. Try it with hard data first and if the reference works then move on to the filtering to make sure it works. The code worked fine as is with my test data.

Comment: When I have the data filtered, the visible range extends from C1372:C2527 with six rows visible. Don't know if that provides you any insight.

Comment: If I include Debug.Print length after I define length, it outputs 1 to the immediate window

Comment: Your issue now sounds like it is having difficulty locating the correct last row based on the way you are trying to find the last row. That method may not work on filtered ranges. I'm not at my PC so I'm not in a good position to help you locate that information but I know there are multiple posts on this site alone which help find the last row in a filtered range. My guess is that the last row is returning 1. So when it does the subtotal, it's doing the subtotal of C2 through C1 which doesn't exist. I will be home from work in a few minutes and will try to help more then.

Comment: No worries @Busse. I'll continue troubleshooting and see if I find something that works in the meantime. Appreciate your help thus far!

Comment: Ok, you have to insert a period prior to calling the Range for length:

length = .Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

Now length will output as 2527. My subtotal is still incorrect though, let me see if I can fix that.